# apps in my ubuntu 14.04 are freezing repeatedly/ not responding

Tags: 14.04

I have bought a new dell pc, preloaded with ubuntu, which happens to be a nes OS for me
I am facing frequent instances of the OS freezing, any one of its apps freezing, as if its not able to process the data
Bluetooth disconnects itself randomly, and unable to update the software as well
kindly help

PC specs:
dell inspiron 3000 series
Intel® Core™ i3-5005U CPU @ 2.00GHz × 2 (with hyper threading) 4 GB ram
Intel HD 5500 series integrated graphics
OS type 64 bit

Thanks in advance

Comment: As you say this is a new PC from dell with preinstalled Ubuntu, might be better to complain to dell, you should have a guarantee.